# Probability of adding a ball of similar color with the one you just picked in an urn after an infinite amount of time

Tags: probability

This is something a overheard and as a result I may not remember it correctly but the problem discussed went something like this:

*Suppose we have an urn with one white and one black ball. We randomly pick one ball and if its white we add another white ball so we now have two white balls and one black, we do the same if we pick a black ball. What will happen after an infinite amount of doing this regarding the distribution of white and black balls?*

Can someone give me some hints if they know how to solve this?

Comment: There will be an infinite number of both white and black balls with probability one.  You can't really talk about the proportion of black to white if there are infinitely many of both, you have to talk about which has greater density.  But the expected value of that density has to be $1/2$.

Comment: Hmm, interesting problem!  One thought is that maybe as you start to get more of one color, it will 'outpace' the other one, i.e. that you get a kind of 'rich get richer' effect.  And yet, the probability of picking the 'minority' color is never $0$, so the number of them should keep going up as well, so both should go to infinity and since it's countably infinite for both, one can argue that it would end up as the 'same' amount for each.  Paradoxical for sure! Maybe the issue is that there is no real 'after' here .... Ugh. Infinity!

Comment: @GregoryGrant How do you define the density so that you can compute its expected value (which I agree must be $1/2$ by symmetry) ? As the limit (in some sense) of the proportion of white? Why isn't that $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ each? Care to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: So by symmetry, the expected distribution is 50/50 ... but to actually get 50/50 seems unlikely (never mind that you would have to 'complete' an infinite process).  And it is not one of those expected outcomes of throwing 1 die, which is 3.5 and which as an outcome itself is impossible, but I intuit it would be super unlikely to even get anywhere *near* 50/50 as an actual outcome  ... someone run a simulation and do this a gazillion times, please! ... my intuition is that there are only 2 'stable' outcomes: close to 100% white and 0% black or vice versa ... is this true or am I full of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known problem called "Polya's urn model".

After you draw once you will have either two white balls and one black ball, or two black and one white, with probability 1/2.

Now consider the second draw.  The chance that you have three white and one black after this draw is (1/2) * (2/3) - you have to start with two white and one black, and then draw a white. The chance that you have two white and two black after this draw is (1/2) * (1/3) + (1/2) * (1/3) = 1/3 - there are two different ways to get to this state. And the chance of having one white and three black is also 1/3.

You may be able to guess the answer now. If not, keep calculating.

Comment: No I can :) Your answer makes perfect sense.